# sort a string list(URL's) by frequency and remove duplicates

Tags: python, algorithm, dictionary, data-structures

I have given a list containing website URL's. If the elements have the same frequency, sort them in lexicographical order without importing any extra libraries or packages.

```py
def solve (S, N):
    # write your code here
    n = len(S)
    dict = {}
    for i in S:
        if i in dict:
            dict[i]+=1
        else:
            dict[i]=0
    return dict
```

I tried doing this but the elements which have same frequency are getting printed in the same order as input is given.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you never sorted the dictionary, not even by frequency.

Counting occurrences in a dictionary is quite common, so there is a convenient class in the standard library named [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) which makes this a lot simpler. If the standard library counts as an "extra" library for your purposes, then you can just use your original loop to build the dictionary; the important part is how to sort it after you've counted the frequencies.

```py
from collections import Counter

def order_by_frequency(urls):
    counts = Counter(urls)
    return sorted(counts, key=lambda url: (-counts[url], url))
```

The key function returns a tuple, so that the `url` string is used as a tie-breaker when two urls have the same frequency. The `-` sign means they are sorted with the highest frequency first; if you want the lowest frequency first, just remove the `-`.

Comment: You missed _without importing any extra libraries or packages_ in OP.

Comment: `collections` is part of the standard library; it is available without installing any extra libraries or packages. My answer addresses the case where even `collections` is not allowed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sorted()` to sort by values and than by keys

```
data = solve(S, N)
sorted_data = sorted(data.items(), key=lambda x: [-x[1], x[0]])

for sd in sorted_data:
    print(f'{sd[0]}: {sd[1]}')
```